# How to catch an exception thrown by a module at loading?

Tags: typescript, exception, es6-modules

I am going to validate environment variables and show the page with an error message if environment is invalid. Can I do it this way?

`config.ts` throws exception if `env` is invalid

```
import * as yup from 'yup'

console.log(process.env)

const envSchema = yup.object({
  REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL: yup
    .string()
    .required()
    .url()
    .label('REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL')
})

export default envSchema.validateSync(process.env)
```

`index.ts` loads `config.ts`. Can it catch its exception?

```
//try {  import cannot be inside try
import config from 'config' //exception thrown if env is invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using that syntax, no, but this is possible using dynamic imports.

https://mariusschulz.com/blog/dynamic-import-expressions-in-typescript has some good TypeScript examples & explanations for dynamic imports.

In your case, this would look something like:

```js
const config = import('config').catch((error) => {
  // Do something if you get an error
});
```

Note that this makes loading asynchronous, so `config` will be a promise for the module value, not just the value itself, and the rest of your code won't automatically wait until that loading has been completed. You'll need to explicitly `await config` where you want to use it or similar.

The issue with the normal import syntax is that it's designed to be extracted and executed statically, before actually running any of the code in that file, which means you don't have anywhere where you can set up any error handling.

Notably once TypeScript 3.7 comes out, you'll be able to use top-level await in modules, so you can turn `config` into a normal module value that subsequent code will automatically wait for as you expect, like so:

```js
const config = await import('config').catch((error) => {
  // Do something if you get an error
});
```

There is one last option: if you're using commonjs modules, you could fall back to a synchronous `require('config')` call:

```js
let config: any;
try {
  config = require('config');
} catch (e) {
  // Do something if you get an error
}
```

This will do what you expect, but you lose typing (fixable, but tricky to do well), and in general I would recommend moving towards ES modules rather than fighting against them, since they're the standard.